# How do I unblock website in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, hosts

I have blocked youtube.com website using gedit `/etc/hosts` file. Then I have removed the entries in hosts file. Even though the websites are blocked  permanently. How can I unblock Youtube again?

Comment: Please provide more information on what exactly you did. If you removed the entries you added to `/etc/hosts` file then you should be able to access that site without issues. What is the error you are getting when trying to access it?

Answer (score 0):

to find out the IP address of a web-site you may visit this [conver host to IP](http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm)
please add a new entry in **/etc/hosts** file with the IP address of the website you want to visit in your case youtube.com. Here is for example: add in your hosts file

`216.58.208.142      www.youtube.com       # put IP address and its hostname`

then run

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking start`

You should be able to visit a site again. Moreover, any route is specified in the file **/etc/hosts** are prioritised by the system.

Comment: Changes in `/etc/hosts` are immediate, unless you have nscd or something similar running. You don't need to do the `/etc/init.d/` thing.

Comment: Yes you are right but I put in case in **/etc/hosts** file contains    both   `127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
216.58.208.142 www.youtube.com
` then a start is needed to access the site again though having the first entry is useless